# Populating a string array using a string? (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, arrays

I was looking around the site for some similar answers but I haven't found anything so far.  I am wondering how I can populate a string array with a pre-established string.  Also, if I have a separate class, would I include this code in a method or in a constructor?

The string:

```
String stateList = "Alabama^Alaska^Arizona^Arkansas^California^Colorado^Connecticut^Delaware^Florida^"
            + "Georgia^Hawaii^Idaho^Illinois^Indiana^Iowa^Kansas^Kentucky^Louisiana^Maine^Maryland^"
            + "Massachusetts^Michigan^Minnesota^Mississippi^Missouri^Montana^Nebraska^Nevada^"
            + "New Hampshire^New Jersey^New Mexico^New York^North Carolina^North Dakota^Ohio^Oklahoma^"
            + "Oregon^Pennsylvania^Rhode Island^South Carolina^South Dakota^Tennessee^Texas^Utah^"
            + "Vermont^Virginia^Washington^West Virginia^Wisconsin^Wyoming";
```

My attempt (which did not work):

```
String[] stateArray = stateList.split(" ^ ");
    for(int i=0; i < stateArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: You can also instantiate the string array right away. String[] stateArray = new String[]{"Alabama", "Alaska", "and the rest"};

Comment: you don't have spaces around `^` don't use it in split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` character has [special meanings in regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html); provide a backslash character (which itself needs to be escaped in Java), so that split interprets it as a literal `^`:

```
String[] stateArray = stateList.split("\\^");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `split.("\\^")`. This method uses regex, and `^` in regex have [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) (which in this case is start of input data). To escape it you need to pass `\^` to regex engine, so you will need to use `\\^` form.